# Implement a comparable using objects hash codes

Tags: java

I have a general method that needs to sort and search for generic objects,

**Old Version**:

```
    public <T> int isIn(T[] list, T t) {

       Arrays.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(Object::hashCode));  
 return Arrays.binarySearch(values,updatedObject.hashCode())

    }
```

**New Version:**

```
    public <T> int isIn(T[] list, T t) {

       Arrays.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(Object::hashCode));  
 return Arrays.binarySearch(values,updatedObject.hashCode(),Comparator.comparingInt(Object::hashCode))

    }
```

Assuming that hashcode() is implemented properly, I can't think of any case where this could fail or give any error. 
What are the cases, if any, that this could give us an error !

NOTE: Code is edited, I added Comparator to the binary search

Comment: It can't possibly work if you don't pass the same comparator to binarySearch. And it will also fail if two different objects have the same hashCode, because the comparator will consider that they are equal.

Comment: There is no point in sorting and then searching, even if you're using binary search: it's still more complex than just linearly searching the list. At best, the list is sorted already; but you have to pass over every element to determine this. Just look for the element in this pass.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few issues with your code.

1. `hashCode` is used to infer object inequality. Meaning that two objects may virtually have the same `hashCode` and yet an `equals` invocation may return `false` (see also [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())). In this case, the outcome of `binarySearch` may yield unexpected results (see also [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object))).
2. `binarySearch` invocations without passing a `Comparator` assume that your objects are sorted based on their natural ordering, which implies they are `Comparable` (which we cannot know with your code). If your objects were not `Comparable`, you would get a `ClassCastException` when invoking `binarySearch` as you do. You would at the very least need to use the `Comparator` employed when sorting the array, and pass it to your `binarySerach` invocation (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T[],%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)) for overload API).

**Note**: OP added `Comparator` and edited question - only valid with previous version of the question.

3. As a general OO guideline, you may want to rethink what objects you are going to use your `isIn` method with, and maybe bind the generic type to a broad type that yields enough information in terms of properties to have a natural order, or at least to be sortable using a `Comparator` based on properties that it makes sense to sort with. TL;DR the hash code's purpose is not to sort objects.
4. Following up on point 3, you'd expect an `isIn` method to return a boolean type, not an integer type. If your goal is simply to infer whether your array contains a given value, override `equals` in the objects passed, wrap your array in a suitable `Collection` and invoke [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: @Adelin I don't really see the purpose in your edit at this point.

Comment: sorry this is the current code, I mistakenly copied an old code

Answer (score 1):

Your code will produce an index of an object with the same hash code, but since objects are allowed to have the same hash code without being equal, you need to perform some additional work before returning the result.

Walk the list of items with the same hash code until you find equality, find a different hash code, or go off the end of the array:

```
public <T> int isIn(T[] list, T t) {
    Comparator<T> cmp = Comparator.comparingInt(Object::hashCode);
    Arrays.sort(list, cmp);
    int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(list, t, cmp);
    if (pos < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    // At this point pos is a valid index, but it may not be of the same object
    // Continue with a linear search of the equal range of hash codes from here:
    int hash = t.hashCode();
    while (pos != list.length()) {
        if (t.equals(list[pos]) {
            return pos;
        }
        if (list[pos].hashCode() != hash) {
            return -1;
        }
        pos++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Note:** Although this is consistent with the way the `hashCode`/`equals` are supposed to be used in Java, the approach is less efficient than using a `HashSet<T>`, because it requires O(n*log n) sorting step.

Answer (score 1):

This should fail; because, when two objects contain the same hashcode the order will be unspecified.  The contract on hash codes is that all objects returning `equals(...)` as true have the same hashcode, not all equal hashcodes have `equals(...)` return true.

Hashcodes are not unique, that's why we have the hashcode act as the first means of determining cheap equality, but always have to follow up with the `equals(...)` method afterwards.

Now, the `equals(...)` method doesn't provide comparision (ordering, so you'll have to back it  up with a `Comparator` for the object anyway.  Since you initially ordered on hashcode, your `Comparator` will have to provide orderings that don't violate the hascode-first approach.

```
  // pseudocode
  unless hashcodes are equal, return the value of Comparator.comparingInt()
  when hashcodes are equal, pick some stable ordering.
```

Note that this would work well within it's bubble of your code; but, if you wanted to assure that someone didn't break this in the future, you might need to also add a `Comparable` interface to your object, and have it return the "hashcode, then sub-ordering" with the same logic as your `Comparator`.

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming that hashcode() is implemented properly

This is a big assumption as Java's library classes (e.g. `String`) themselves have collision in `hashCode()` values, e.g.

```
System.out.println("Aa".hashCode() + "," + "BB".hashCode());
```

This will print the same hash code and hence, comparator will consider both the objects equal.